# Seaborn: Include multiple 'HUE' in one graph?

Tags: python, csv, seaborn

I have simple python script for reading CSV file and plotting graphs using seaborn, and it works perfectly!

firstly: here is a screenshot of my CSV file showing the frames and the statistics for stations:
[image]

here is my simple code:

```
import pandas as pd import matplotlib.pyplot as plt import seaborn as sns

read_CSV_stats_per_day_for_KS = pd.read_csv('results_per_day/ALL_stations_together.csv', sep=";", encoding ="ISO-8859-1")
read_day_column = read_CSV_stats_per_day_for_KS[read_CSV_stats_per_day_for_KS['day'] == 0]

def plot_results_about_south_east_stations():
    south_east = read_day_column[read_day_column['Region'] == 'south_east']
    top4_visited_stations = south_east.nlargest(4, 'total_visited_cars')

   dataframes_for_south_east_stations = read_CSV_stats_per_day_for_KS[read_CSV_stats_per_day_for_KS['name'].isin(top4_visited_stations['name'])]

   sns.relplot(x='day', y='avg_queue_length', data=dataframes_for_south_east_stations, hue='name', kind='line')
plt.suptitle("South-east Oslo")

   sns.relplot(x='day', y='avg_total_EV_in_station', data=dataframes_for_south_east_stations, hue='name', kind='line')
plt.suptitle("South-east Oslo")

   sns.relplot(x='day', y='total_rejected_cars', data=dataframes_for_south_east_stations, hue='name', kind='line')
plt.suptitle("South-east Oslo")

   sns.relplot(x='day', y='total_exhausted_cars', data=dataframes_for_south_east_stations, hue='name', kind='line')
plt.suptitle("South-east Oslo")

   plt.show()
```

When i plot, I get those beautiful graphs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7CGU.jpg

If you look on the graphs below(exactly the same), I am trying to replace the name of stations with total_amount_of_chargers that particular station has

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5gCg.jpg

qustion 1: firstly, the numbers are wrong, i want to show the actual number of chargers, not those 20, 40,60,80. How can i do that?

question 2: I still want the name of stations to stay on the Y label instead of numbers, how can i do that?

qustion 3: the final qustion, Is it possible to combine the name of stations and total amount of chargers to show on the right? like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iio1l.jpg

It this were possible, it would be awesome and i would be very appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: First, you should provide some code to help us manipulate a sample dataset that is relevant to your matter (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Second, have you tried to actually manipulate your dataframe and read the full seaborn API before asking Q1 and Q2 ?

Comment: "First, you should provide some code to help us manipulate a sample dataset"? I suppose you mean you want to have the access to the file? because this is the only code i have to read and plot graphs